# python BaseHTTPServer file upload with maxfile-size

Tags: python, file, size, max, basehttpserver

If the file is to big i dont want to download it to my server and then delete it, I just want to tell the user that the file is to big. 
this code almost accomplish this. if the file is smaller than 10 mb it get upload and the user get a response that the file has been uploaded. but if the file is larger than 10 mb the user dont get any response, the browser just says that it has lost the connection with the server.

```
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

import cgi

class StoreHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        if int(self.headers['content-length']) > 10000000:
            print "file to big"
            self.send_response("file to big")
            return

        else:
            form = cgi.FieldStorage(
                fp=self.rfile,
                headers=self.headers,
                environ={'REQUEST_METHOD':'POST',
                         'CONTENT_TYPE':self.headers['Content-Type'],
                         })
            filename = form['file'].filename
            data = form['file'].file.read()
            open("/tmp/%s"%filename, "wb").write(data)
            print self.headers['content-length']
            self.respond("uploaded %s, thanks")

    def do_GET(self):
        response = """
        <html><body>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <p>File: <input type="file" name="file"></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Upload"></p>
        </form>
        </body></html>
        """        

        self.respond(response)

    def respond(self, response, status=200):
        self.send_response(status)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.send_header("Content-length", len(response))
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(response)  


server = HTTPServer(('', 8080), StoreHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: You've used `send_response("file to big")` instead of `respond("file to big")` in "over 10mb" case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have got to read all request data in any case. Otherwise HTTP client (browser) just don't get it.

In first case when file is too big, you can just read and ignore data.

Here is updated StoreHandler:

```
class StoreHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        length = int(self.headers['content-length'])
        print length
        if length > 10000000:
            print "file to big"
            read = 0
            while read < length:
                read += len(self.rfile.read(min(66556, length - read)))
            self.respond("file to big")
            return
        else:
            form = cgi.FieldStorage(
                fp=self.rfile,
                headers=self.headers,
                environ={'REQUEST_METHOD':'POST',
                         'CONTENT_TYPE':self.headers['Content-Type'],
                         })
            filename = form['file'].filename
            data = form['file'].file.read()
            open("/tmp/%s"%filename, "wb").write(data)
            print self.headers['content-length']
            self.respond("uploaded %s, thanks")
```

Comment: Are you sure that i have to read thorugh all the data? to me it seams strange that i have to read all data even dough i dont want all data..

Comment: I am pretty sure. That how it works with many HTTP clients. They don't read response until they send all request data. This [q&a](http://serverfault.com/questions/360479/why-might-a-413-not-be-flushed-to-the-client-immediately) might help you

Comment: 4 years later... :)  I'm suspecting @DmitryNedbaylo is wrong. It looks like the best way to allow your server be killed by hostile uploaders. just because you want to be nice to the browser, you allow your server to be stuck reading giant files. There must be a way to 'drop the line' without reading everything!

Comment: @ishahak you are right, there are other techniques to achieve that, e.g. AJAX and realtime notifications via WebSocket. But not with the plain post request in a browser, if you want to be nice to your users.