# Save file from POST request to disk without storing in memory with Python's BaseHTTPServer

Tags: python-2.x, httpserver

I'm writing an HTTP server in Python 2 with BaseHTTPServer, and it's assumed that it accepts multiple connections at the same time, on each connection the user can send a large file through a POST request. However my understanding is that the whole request will be stored in the server's memory before being processed, and multiple uploaded file at the same time can exceed the amount of memory on the server. Is there any way to, instead of storing the file/request in memory, stream it to a file on disk directly?

Answer (score 0):

[BaseHTTPServer doesn't come with a POST handler out of the box](https://docs.python.org/2/library/basehttpserver.html#BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler), so you'll have to implement it yourself or find an implementation that works for you. (These are easy to search for; [here's one I found that looked straightforward](https://blog.anvileight.com/posts/simple-python-http-server/).

Your question is similar to [this question about limiting the max-size of POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28217869/python-basehttpserver-file-upload-with-maxfile-size); the [answer points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28220558/11639518) you'll need to read through all that data in order to ensure proper browser functionality. The comments to that answer seem to indicate the use of other techniques ("e.g. AJAX and realtime notifications via WebSocket." @dmitry-nedbaylo)